# How do I get only the value of an object?

Tags: javascript

I use TypeScript.
I want to get only the value of an object, but this error occurs: *“`TypeError`: Cannot read properties of `undefined` (reading '`cd1`')”*.

```js
callList = {
  cd1: "00001",
  nm1: "17"
}

// cd = '17'
const getFindbyNm(cd) => {
  const idx = callList.find(e => e.nm1 == cd)

  console.log(idx['cd1']); // ← Error occuered.
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Clearly, `callList` must be an Array, so please [edit] your post and provide a [mre]. How are you calling `getFindbyNm`? Did you forget to pass the argument for the parameter `cd`? Then it’s a duplicate of [Why is a global variable undefined inside a function when I call it?](/q/15309718/4642212).

Comment: callList is not a  list actually, possibly a typo ?  A List of object will look like this `[{cd1: "00001",
  nm1: "17"}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't properly structured, it's not really valid JS even.

With some code cleaning, it works, but as some have stated, you need to use an Array for `.find()` to work.

```js
const callList = {
  cd1: "00001",
  nm1: "17"
};

const cd = '17';
const getFindbyNm = (param1, param2) => {
  return param1.find(e => e.nm1 == param2);
};

console.log(getFindbyNm([callList], cd));
console.log(getFindbyNm([callList], cd).cd1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering `callList` is an Array

```
const callList =
  [{
    cd1: "00001",
    nm1: "17"
  }]
```

`Array.prototype.find` returns an array item or `undefined`, as an item may not be found within the given array. This is why `idx` may be undefined, hence `cd1` may not exist on `undefined`

To fix it you can either check if `idx` isn't undefined

```
  if(idx){ 
    console.log(idx['cd1']);
  }
```

or use the optional chaining operator `?.`

```
console.log(idx?.['cd1'])
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGAbRAZAltGBeAUDGA2gN575wAmAjAFwwBEADEw5XQDSn5gC2N9lAdjqkAvgF0cOAPRSK2GAHJBCnKEiwA5gFMoAMTRhyAIwCeAOW7yAFMHK1oAJwMaAlNgB8MEvjWY05AA95BGR0aAA6ADMDcistDxgtcJ5KbCwKF1JfEEQkxBANK38AggVbSgUxTJFJX00dfUNTCwAFEAgINCNc-QDU9Js7GEdnNyxPbzhwP0DgpFQMKCiYuISklLSM0jRIosCXIhhOKcgcvIK9krKqSpcAbjIZGEAEwkAABi0HBxAHGBBgYAArh8tORRDgaqppvU9DFmtw2h0uj00AEAEzWWz2KBOMCuBKTOowYpzUKLZaGVbjRLJXibWyZHzTM7hfKFYoAfnCpXKt3BQA)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) instead of `find` since  `find` is function in `array` not in `object`. [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) has the attributes of both the `key` and the `value`

```js
const callList = {
  cd1: "00001",
  nm1: "17",
};

const getFindByNm = (cd) => {
  let returnval;
  Object.entries(callList).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (key == 'nm1' && value == cd) {
      returnval = value;
    }
  });
  return returnval;
};

let val = getFindByNm("17");
console.log(val);
```